# I can't Import import retrofit.GsonConverterFactory; in Retrofit 2 beta 4

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to use GsonConvertFactory.create()
but when i try to import
import retrofit.GsonConverterFactory;

i don't find the package in Retrofit 2

Comment: Please give the exact code and error message. Also include the dependencies from build.gradle.

Comment: GsonConverterFactory.create() can't import GsonConverter because the Retrofit2 gives you the option to choose your converter

Comment: Please edit your question to include this information so that you can format it properly.

Answer (score 3):

Add `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'` to your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Fast Solution
you can change you retrofit dependency to 
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
but be aware the retrofit 2 work a bit differently about retrofit
asynch requests you call

for example

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://www.github.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    client = retrofit.create(YOUR_INTERFACE.class);
    Call<JsonObject> call = client.getNews();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<JsonObject> response
                , Retrofit retrofit) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        }
    });
```

for more detail you can check 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html
http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en

Answer (score 0):

It seems the library has been moved. The `2.0.0-beta4` didn't work for me. `2.3.0` does.
[image]